# Finagle client in Scala Play Controller

Tags: scala, playframework, finagle

I'm using a method(FinagleClient.longRunningComputation) of Finagle client in my controller

```
def alfa = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>

    val response = FinagleClient.longRunningComputation(request.body )          
    response.map( rest => Ok("Got result: " + rest ))

}
```

I need to get the result of the com.twitter.util.Future in my play Controller

I try using [Returning futures](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAsync) , but the compiler, return the following error:

```
found   : com.twitter.util.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]

response.map(rest => Ok("Got result: " + rest))
```

I need to use a com.twitter.util.Future in my play Controller

How Can I Do This?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to convert to `scala.concurrent.Future`, which you can do using `Promise`.

Something like this:

```
def alfa = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    val p = Promise[Result]
    val response = FinagleClient.longRunningComputation(request.body )          
    val twitterFuture = response.map( rest => Ok("Got result: " + rest ))
    twitterFuture.onSuccess(p.success)
    twitterFuture.onFailure(p.failure)

    p.future
}
```

We can generalize this to implicitly convert `com.twitter.util.Future[A]` to `scala.concurrent.Future[A]`.

```
import com.twitter.util.{Future => TwitterFuture}
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}

object TwitterConversions {
    def twitter2Scala[A](f: TwitterFuture[A]): Future[A] = {
        val p = Promise[A]
        f.onSuccess(p.success)
        f.onFailure(p.failure)
        p.future
    }
}
```

Then all you would need to do in your controller is `import TwitterConversions._` (or whatever package you put it in).

Comment: There are [officially supported converters](https://github.com/twitter/bijection/blob/master/bijection-util/src/main/scala/com/twitter/bijection/twitter_util/UtilBijections.scala#L58) in Twitter's Bijection library.

Comment: @TravisBrown, i got the next error: found   : com.twitter.util.Future[org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse], required: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext, val futureScala = twitter2ScalaFuture( FinagleClient.documentSearch( json ) ), my code is here: https://github.com/hectorgool/es-client/blob/master/app/controllers/ElasticSearch.scala

Comment: @user1034380 With the right imports (see the bijection README) you can just write e.g. `Future(1).as[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]]`. Alternatively you could create a bijection instance and then call it directly.